# An Issue with pushing elements to a nested array

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I want to push new elements to an array:

```
var temp = [];
for(var i in resultDb){     
    temp.push({'ID':resultDb[i].ID});
    temp.push({'Label':resultDb[i].Label});
    temp.push({'User':[{'Name':resultDb[i].Name , 'ScreenName':resultDb[i].ScreenName}]});
    temp.push({'TDate':resultDb[i].TDate});
}

for(var i in temp){
    console.log(temp[i].User.ScreenName);
}
```

The result that I got is `Cannot read property 'ScreenName' of undefined`. The problem specifically is with `User` but the others are fine; they can be printed.

Comment: `User` is an array. please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = [];
//this loop pushes 4 elements in the array for each element in resultDb
for(var i in resultDb){     
    temp.push({'ID':resultDb[i].ID});
    temp.push({'Label':resultDb[i].Label});
    //why an array here?
    temp.push({'User':[{'Name':resultDb[i].Name , 'ScreenName':resultDb[i].ScreenName}]});
    temp.push({'TDate':resultDb[i].TDate});
}

//...therefore you have resultDb.length * 4 elements in temp.
//and only 1 every 4 elements has a User property
for(var i in temp){
    console.log(temp[i].User.ScreenName);
}
```

You were probably trying to do this:

```
var temp = [];
for(var i in resultDb){     
    temp.push(Object.assign(
        {'ID':resultDb[i].ID},
        {'Label':resultDb[i].Label},
        {'User':{'Name':resultDb[i].Name, 'ScreenName':resultDb[i].ScreenName}},
        {'TDate':resultDb[i].TDate}
    ));
}

for(var i in temp){
    console.log(temp[i].User.ScreenName);
}
```

Here's an even better way of doing that:

```
var temp = resultDb.map(function (result) {
    return Object.assign(
        {'ID':result.ID},
        {'Label':result.Label},
        {'User':{'Name':result.Name, 'ScreenName':result.ScreenName}},
        {'TDate':result.TDate}
    );
})

for(var i in temp){
    console.log(temp[i].User.ScreenName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how arrays work. You're just pushing new objects to your array. All of the objects you're pushing have a different structure. So, the first entry in your array does not have the user property to begin with.

User will result in undefined, hence the: Cannot read property 'ScreenName' of undefined.

What you're trying to do here is taking the {'ID':result.ID} object, and try to read the user property from it, but it only has an ID property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all temp should be an object, not an array, {} instead of [].

For "Cannot read property 'ScreenName' of undefined"

There's 2 ways to approach this, usually you verify both.

```
if( typeof resultDb[i] == 'undefined' )
  return false;// index is not valid ?

var some_value = ( typeof resultDb[i].ScreenName == 'undefined' ? false : resultDb[i].ScreenName );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared User as an array,

```
for(var i in temp){
    console.log(temp[i].hasOwnProperty("User") ? temp[i].User[0].ScreenName : "not found");
}
```